# Visit Germany from Vietnam

Tags: visas, germany, paperwork, vietnam

I'm planning to invite a friend to come to Germany over Christmas. I will pay everything for this trip including plane tickets, since my friend can't afford this trip at all and can't prove any income.
Through some research I found out I'm supposed to show the original of a document that I have to fill out to prove that I can afford to invite this person.

**Does this mean I have to send a physical document to Vietnam to my friend for the Visa? Is there any easier way?**

Comment: Could you provide a link to the place that shows you that you need this document? Does this document have a name?

Comment: According to [this (Besuchssreise)](http://www.ho-chi-minh-stadt.diplo.de/Vertretung/hochiminh/de/01/Visabestimmungen/seite__Merkbl_C3_A4tter.html) document, I will need to send something to invite him (Nr. 3) and a "original" of the "Verpflichtungserklärung gem. §§ 66-68". Do they mean bringing the "original" to the "Amt" in Germany or to the embassy in Vietnam?

Comment: The biggest issue is the visa. Please check carefully if for all document requested. German visa or Europe visa requests so many things

Comment: The document on the linked-to site is pretty explicit, you need to hand one original and one photocopy of all valid passports (with accredited translation if the document is neither German nor English) to the German consulate, as well as the filled out form and 2 passport photos. Presumably your friend would do that, since otherwise he needs to mail his passport to you. The Verpflichtungserklärung must be handed in (with photocopy) by you, at the local Ausländerbehörde. Plus credit info, bank data for 6 months, etc. -- as stated in the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This website](http://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/DE/Infoservice/FAQ/VisumFuerD/03-Einladung.html?nn=350374) contains all the pertinent information. Specifically, it says that while your friend as to apply for the visa at the German embassy in Vietnam, your "Verpflichtungserklärung" should be submitted to the "Ausländerbehörden" in your hometown. Presumably it will then contact the embassy.

But there looms a bigger problem:

> Die Auslandsvertretungen müssen zudem insbesondere zur "Rückkehrbereitschaft" und "Rückkehrmöglichkeit" des Reisenden eine positive Prognose abgeben. Auch hierzu ist der Nachweis ggfs. durch geeignete Dokumente zu erbringen.

This is not something you can influence - basically, your friend has to convince the German embassy that he will return to Vietnam. Typically they look for things like family ties (especially marriage) and a steady job.

Comment: Well, I know from my friends side, that he would have to show documents to identify him to be Vietnamese, which won't be any problem. As far as I understand, I could also oblige to pay for the trip for him all in Germany without any document sending. Do they still have to prove that he could "return" ("Rueckkehrmoeglichkeit") from a financial perspective?

Comment: @supercuteboy: A booked return ticket should take care of that, but the real problem is going to be "Rückkehrbereitschaft" - the concern is that he's planning to stay in Germany indefinitely and illegally, and for a young poor male from a third world country it will be hard to allay that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need to provide all necessary information to prove that you are capable of covering all expenses for your friend's travel. The documents must be sent to your Vietnamese friends for his visa application. As I know, this is the only way. There's no other option.